# How to animate the height change of an section header in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've implemented this method to return the section header height. However, when the height for the section changes, it happens immediately without animation.

**Is there an animation for that?**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (flatHeader) {
        return 50.0f;
    } else {
        return 100.0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this will work for a table header but it works for table rows so it's worth a shot. I have an instance variable `headerHeight` initially set to 44.0 and I change it as so:

```
- (void)changeHeight {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    headerHeight = 88.0;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

In my code I return the `headerHeight` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but you can try it in `heightForHeaderInSection`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return headerHeight;
}
```

Comment: thanks @prendio2 that worked well. it wasn't able to remove the view however (which is what i was trying to do). but as soon as i scrolled it was removed, so thats ok :)

Comment: for anyone who has the same use case as me (they want to remove the view), you can keep a reference to it and use the method `removeFromSuperview` on it during the animation to hide it properly.

Comment: This works well, but the area that pops down covers my first UITableViewCell. Any ideas? Any way to shift the tableView down when this happens?

Comment: This worked for me, except it didn't follow the animation duration that I had set up with `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]`

Comment: Guys, where to put this method (changeHeight:). I need to auto animation, when headers is appear. How to call it?

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
flatHeader = YES;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
CGRect frame = [[self headerView] frame];
frame.size.height = [self tableView:[self tableView] heightForHeaderInSection:0];
[[self headerView] setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution in Swift:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var sectionHeaderView:UIView?
```

...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    sectionHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 30))
    sectionHeaderView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 30))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    button.setTitle("collapse/expand", forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "collapseOrExpandSectionHeader", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    sectionHeaderView?.addSubview(button)

    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if let sectionHeader = sectionHeaderView {
        return view.frame.size.height
    } else {
        return 30.0
    }
}
```

...

```
func collapseOrExpandSectionHeader() {

    if let sectionHeader = sectionHeaderView {

        let headerHeight:CGFloat

        if sectionHeader.frame.size.height == 200 {
            headerHeight = 30.0
        } else {
            headerHeight = 200.0
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
            sectionHeader.frame.size.height = headerHeight
            self.tableView?.endUpdates()
        } )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this, but sometimes I get unwanted animations when my UITableViewCells change height.  The cause of this is that I draw my own cells, and I use CALayers to do so.  In the cell's `(void)layoutSubviews` I would change the size of my CALayer to be the size of the frame for the cell

```
myLayer.frame = self.bounds;
```

When the frame/bounds property of a CALayer changes, it is animated. So in theory, I would say that you could use the method tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: which would allow you to draw your own section header.  You could just return a UIView that implements `(void)layoutSubviews` and then in that method do

```
self.layer.frame = self.bounds;
```

Just an idea.