# How to animate UITableView header view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation

I need to animate the insertion of a tableview header view. I want that the table rows to slide down while the header view expands its frame.
So far the best result I got is by using the following code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];  
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.someHeaderView];  
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

The problem with this solution is that the header itself doesn't get animated, its frame doesn't expand.

So the effect I'm getting is that the table rows slide down (as I want) but the header view is immediately shown, and I want it to expand it's frame with animation.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659428/how-to-animate-the-height-change-of-an-section-header-in-uitableview

Comment: Somthings should be easier : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777106/how-to-animate-the-height-changing-of-a-header-in-section-of-a-tableview

Answer (score 27, accepted):

have the header frame at `CGRectZero`
and set its frame using animation

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];  
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:self.someHeaderView];  

[UIView animateWithDuration:.5f animations:^{
  CGRect theFrame = someBigger.frame;
  someHeaderView.frame = theFrame;
}];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it looks like if you set the table's header with a view with height zero, then no matter if you latter change this view height, the table's header wont change..

Comment: then try and increase the height for the TableHeaderView in the animation instead of the someHeaderView frame

Comment: The `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls are not required.

Comment: If you want to move the tableView rows and footer as well (and you almost certainly do), you can trigger this with either `begin/endUpdates` or by re-setting `tableView.tableViewHeader = tableView.tableViewHeader` (not just the frame).

Comment: @AndreasLey The `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls are not necessarily required, but they ensure that rows aren't hidden before the animation finishes

Comment: For me, it only works if I include the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls. iOS 9

Answer (score 18):

Here's what I got to work in Swift, with an initial frame height of zero and updating it to its full height in the animations closure:

```
// Calculate new frame size for the table header
var newFrame = tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame
newFrame.size.height = 42

// Get the reference to the header view
let tableHeaderView = tableView.tableHeaderView

// Animate the height change
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6) {
    tableHeaderView.frame = newFrame
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
})
```

Comment: This works for me. In order for the header size and the tableCell moving animations to sync up, I had to use an animationDuration of 0.3. On iOS 9 that is.

Comment: Reassigning the tableHeaderView in the animation block worked for me as well. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

The selected answer didn't work for me.  Had to do the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f
                 animations: ^{
                     CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
                     frame.size.height = self.headerViewController.preferredHeight;
                     self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
                     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
                   }];
```

The really peculiar part is that this works in one view but not in a subclass of the same view controller / view hierarchy.

Comment: Why is `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;` required?  It doesn't work without this seemingly redundant line.

Comment: @OpenUserX03 Agreed that it is redundant but reseting the frame was required for it work for me.

Comment: @OpenUserX03 I saw the same thing, I have to re-set the `tableHeaderView` to get the tableView to notice the new size. They probably do something in the `didSet`, seeing as it's a class reference, not a struct, so just a pointer is to an identical location. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518580/how-to-animate-uitableview-header-view/16518713#comment61586382_16518713

Answer (score 1):

I found the definitive and proper way to achieve a real animation on `tableHeaderView`s!

• First, if you're in `Autolayout`, keep the `Margin` system inside your header view. With Xcode 8 its now possible (at last!), just do not set any constraint to any of the header subviews. You'll have to set the correct margins thought.

• Then use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, but put `endUpdate` **into** the animation block.

```
// [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView]; // not needed if already there
[self.tableView beginUpdates]; 
CGRect headerFrame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds;
headerFrame.size.height = PLAccountHeaderErrorHeight;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds = headerFrame;

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}];
```

Note: I only tried in iOS10, i'll post an update when my iOS9 simulator will be downloaded.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in iOS9 as well as iOS10: the header itself does not change its height, but header subviews seem to move as if the header bounds changed.

Answer (score 1):

### SWIFT 4 SOLUTION w/ Different Header

If you want this kind of animation, that is the solution that I have used: (even though in my case I had also to play a bit with the opacity of the objects, since I was loading another completely different header)

```
fileprivate func transitionExample() {

    let oldHeight = tableView.tableHeaderView?.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height ?? 0

    let newHeader = YourCustomHeaderView()
    newHeader.hideElements() // If you want to play with opacity.

    let smallHeaderFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newHeader.frame.width, height: oldHeight)
    let fullHeaderFrame = newHeader.frame

    newHeader.frame = smallHeaderFrame

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { [weak self] in
        self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
        newHeader.showElements() // Only if have hided the elements before.
        self?.tableView.tableHeaderView = newHeader
        self?.tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = fullHeaderFrame
        self?.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

So, basically, it's all about changing the frame inside the `.animate` closure. The beging/end updates is needed in order to move and update the other elements of the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift 5 UITableView extension for changing the headerView or changing its height, animated using AutoLayout

```
extension UITableView {

func animateTableHeader(view: UIView? = nil, frame: CGRect? = nil) {
    self.tableHeaderView?.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {() -> Void in
        let hView = view ?? self.tableHeaderView
        if frame != nil {
            hView?.frame = frame!
        }
        self.tableHeaderView = hView
        self.tableHeaderView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For me it is animated when using Auto Layout without any explicit animation block or manipulating frames.

```swift
// `tableHeaderViewHeight` is a reference to the height constraint of `tableHeaderView`
tableHeaderViewHeight?.constant = .leastNormalMagnitude

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code this works

```
extension UITableView {

 func hideTableHeaderView() -> Void {
    self.beginUpdates()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.tableHeaderView = nil
    })
    self.endUpdates()
}

func showTableHeaderView(header: UIView) -> Void {
    let headerView = header
    self.beginUpdates()
    let headerFrame = headerView.frame
    headerView.frame = CGRect()
    self.tableHeaderView = headerView
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.tableHeaderView?.frame = headerFrame
        self.tableHeaderView?.alpha = 0
        self.endUpdates()
    }, completion: { (ok) in
        self.tableHeaderView?.alpha = 1
    })
   }
}
```