# How to animate the height changing of a header in section of a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.3, Swift.

Could you tell me how to animate the height changing of a header in section of a tableview?

- A search bar is put in header in section.
- The search bar is switched to show and hide by tapping navigation bar button.(show: height of header = 44, hide: height of header = 0)
- I would like to animate when switching the search bar show and hide.

The code is as follows. The height of a header in section is immediately changed without animation...

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let array = ["apple", "orange", "melon", "banana", "peach"]

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var searchButtonTapped = false   // Search bar is displayed or not

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchButtonTapped = false
        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchTapped))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchButton
    }

    @objc func searchTapped() {

        if searchButtonTapped == true {
            searchButtonTapped = false
            searchBar.text = nil
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            searchButtonTapped = true
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    // change the height of header in section
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if searchButtonTapped == true {
            return 44
        } else {
            return 0.1
        }
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
        return searchBar
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use a `UISearchController` and it's delegate functions? it automatically includes a searchBar and deals with showing it, animating it into navigationBar on activate (if wanted).

Comment: use `UIViewController` with `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` is another  solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.tableView.reloadData()` is without animation.

you can try

`reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)` or 
`reloadSections(sections: IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

Comment: The problem was solved and I could what I wanted to do. Thank you very much for your help! `self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .automatic)`