# How to custom animation when display a Section?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I want hide/display a section for some conditions in code :

```
if condition == true{
  section.hidden = false
}else{
  section.hidden = true
}
section.evaluateHidden()
```

It's worked,But I want run some custom animation when Section display...

I find a callback name sectionsHaveBeenAdded :

```
override func sectionsHaveBeenAdded(_ sections: [Section], at indexes: IndexSet) {

}
```

Is that right???

Or how to do that and Where to write custom animation code???
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you to animate while hide,unhide view

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.section.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }) { (completed:Bool) in
                // Completion block
                self.section.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.3)
                self.section.isOpaque = true
            }
```

Comment: Is Section in Eureka have property transform??? Why My don't have section.transform ??? Do you mean Section in UITableView???

Comment: I think you are using only UIVIEW. this transform is only used in UIVIEW

Comment: How could I get "Section" object in UITableView with a Section index???I can't find something type like "Section" in UITableView.Thanks

Comment: try this link. Hope this will owrk for you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518580/how-to-animate-uitableview-header-view?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks!I follow to your link,but seem it's talk about animation for SectionHeader not for Section itself... Did I misunderstand???

Comment: yes you misunderstood.Section header is same as tableview section

Comment: In other words custom animation for SectionHeader equal to custom animation for Section???Am I right???